Firebase authentication is not available
I am currently implementing a function in SwiftUI to log in with an Instagram account.
In SwiftUI, we are using ASWebAuthenticationSession.
I am using Firebase's Authentication to create the authentication function.
However, when I redirect to Firebase, I get this error.
This may happen if browser sessionStorage is inaccessible or accidentally cleared. Some specific scenarios are - 1) Using IDP-Initiated SAML SSO. 2) Using signInWithRedirect in a storage-partitioned browser environment.
I looked into this error, but could not find any good information.
I have written a process to implement that authentication in the code.

class InstagramLoginHelper: NSObject, ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProviding {
    
    func startInstagramLogin() {
        let clientID = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
        let redirectURI = "https://XXXXXXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler"
        let authURL = "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=\(clientID)&redirect_uri=\(redirectURI)&scope=user_profile,user_media&response_type=code"
        let schem = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
        
        if let url = URL(string: authURL) {
            let session = ASWebAuthenticationSession(url: url, callbackURLScheme: schem) { callbackURL, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error during authentication: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                
                if let callbackURL = callbackURL, let code = URLComponents(string: callbackURL.absoluteString)?.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == "code" })?.value {
                 
                    self.loginWithInstagram(authCode: code)
                }
            }
            
            session.presentationContextProvider = self
            session.start()
        }
    }
    
    func loginWithInstagram(authCode: String) {
        // Firebaseのauthインスタンスを取得
        let auth = Auth.auth()
        
        // InstagramのOAuthプロバイダを使用する
        let provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "instagram.com")
        
        // Instagramの認証コードを使って、プロバイダの認証資格情報を生成
        provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { credential, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error during authentication: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            if let credential = credential {
           
                auth.signIn(with: credential) { authResult, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error during Firebase authentication: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    } else {
                        print("Successfully authenticated with Firebase.")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // ASWebAuthenticationPresentationContextProvidingの実装
    func presentationAnchor(for session: ASWebAuthenticationSession) -> ASPresentationAnchor {
        return UIApplication.shared.windows.first { $0.isKeyWindow } ?? ASPresentationAnchor()
    }
}

What I tried was to build the backend with Python Flask, but I still got the same error.
